# SlickGrid dataView linking

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am trying to follow a http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html this tutorial. I downloaded all required `.js` files (core.js, dataview.js, grid.js), but when creating `dataView` variable I get `"undefined"`.

```
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
```

Can anybody explain what is my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following script files included on your HTML page in the correct order:

```
<script src="../slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.grid.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.dataview.js"></script>
```

Check with firebug to make sure the path to the files is correct. Use the script tab to verify that the scripts are actually being loaded.